# Cloning a database into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm starting a project and we need to develop a tool to look into any database (future goal, currently just Microsoft SQL) and then create and populate a MySQL database with the same tables/columns/data.  I've been looking into something like [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/) to get the DB schema into java objects.  I'm hoping there exists a tool to convert those objects into SQL code that I can run against a mySQL server.  It would be nice to not have to write a bunch of messy logic using jdbc (My current solution, which is still better than the old solution, an uncommented perl script that converts every column to LONG TEXT).

Comment: Try MySQL Workbench: http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/.

Comment: @duffymo  Could this be setup as a batch job/scheduled job?  This would need to run fairly often.

Comment: "Fairly often"?  I would imagine that you'd convert each database once and be done with it.  I don't understand your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SchemaCrawler's integration with templating languages such as Apache Velocity or Thymeleaf, and develop a template that can generate a DDL script for MySQL. Please download the [latest SchemaCrawler distribution](https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/releases), and look at the Apache Velocity example.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/)